# Django Multiple Files Upload Using Ajax without forms

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, image-uploading

I have an aplication in Django 2.0 where one user can upload many images of their diplomas at the same time but also, I need to make this with ajax so the page will not reload.

This is my **models.py**

```
class diploma(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(user, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    diploma=models.ImageField(default='nopic.png', null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.diploma
```

And this is my file input in my template **upload.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="images" name="images[]" multiple accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif">
<a onclick="uploadWithAjax()"> Upload Images </a>
```

If you notice, there's no Form html tag. Just an 'a' link that calls the function uploadWithAjax().

This is my script with the uploadWithAjax() function

```
function uploadWithAjax()
{
  var files = $('#images')[0].files;
  $.ajax(
  {
    type: "POST",
    url: "/UploadImages/",
    data: "", //I DON'T KNOW WHAT DATA I HAVE TO PUT HERE
    success: function(result)
    {
      alert('IMAGES UPLOADED');
    }
  });
}
```

I Think I have to send the 'files' variable in the 'data' atribute of ajax, but I'm not sure becouse there are files and dont normal inputs. Please help.

This is my **ajax.py** file, where I recive the images

```
def UploadImages(request):
  diplomas = request.FILES['images'] #I don't know if this is correct
```

I didn't finish the view becouse I don't know how to continue or how to make a register in my bd table for each image I uploaded. Please Help!

Comment: I think this can help you:     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48829089/ajax-django-get-files-from-multiple-file-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function uploadWithAjax() {
  var files = $('#images').prop("files");
  if(files.length > 0) {
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/UploadImages/",
         data: {"images": files}
         success: function(result) {
             alert('IMAGES UPLOADED');
         }
      });
  }
}
```

And there, you just passed a list of image files.